# UITableViewCellStyleValue2 edit text - filling form like

Tags: uitableview, edit

I need to create a form so that the user can edit all cells of the table (about 20).

Can I do it with UITableViewCellStyleValue2? If so, how?

Or do I need to create a subclass of UITableViewCell?

In terms of arquitect, maybe it's better to create a subclass, but anyway, i'll need to edit the table, the textlabel.text property.

What's the best way? And how can I do it?

Thanks,

RL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend adding your own views to the cell's contentView, like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool *arp = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:nil];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        lbl.frame = CGRectMake(3, 2, 160, tv.rowHeight - 4);
        lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lbl.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        lbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
        [lbl release];

        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            lbl.text = @"Cell Name";

            UITextField *textField;
            textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170,
                        tv.rowHeight / 2 - 10, 100, 20)];
            textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
            textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
            textField.placeholder = @"Placeholder";
            textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
            textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            textField.tag = indexPath.row;
            textField.delegate = self;

            [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
            [textField release];
        }

        ...

        [arp drain];
    }

    return [cell autorelease];
}
```

This is just a demonstration but you can see where you need to extend it to support additional cells, etc.

Comment: probably the best is to create a subclass of UITableViewCell, so that i have a method to add the data to a NSDictionary, for example, correct?
In xcode4, with ARC, do I need the NSAutoreleasePool? what is this for? (i'm kind of newbie...).
And after this, i must set the table to allow edition, correct?

Comment: @Rui: I don't think you need to use a subclass but I don't really know what your data is. A common approach is to keep that collection within your view controller somehow, perhaps in a class variable. You shouldn't have to make your cells complicated just to store data relative to your view controller as a whole.

The autorelease pool is just to help memory management since some objects are allocated for each cell.

Comment: i need to have about 20 cells. i'll have a NSDictionary for the tableView. But i think i'll subclass, use your approach. Thanks :)